# When I install apk on android, one scene is black. How to fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I made my game for Android device and I've got a menu, store, info scene and a main scene. The main scene is where I play the game. But when I hit start on the menu it loads the "MainScene" and all I can see is the GUI but nothing else. I can collect items but the scene is just black (except the GUI).

I tested out with a web player and everything was fine then changed to Android and after I installed it (several times) I looked at the black screen.

How to fix this?

(I'm using Unity 4.6.1)

Comment: did you include that scene in the build dialog? otherwise it won't be exported

Comment: Of course I did. As I said, I can see the texts, the countdown, and if I move around (just randomly) I can collect points. I just can't see the objects...

Comment: Here's another thing to check: are your textures bigger than 2048x2048?  If so, Android seems to just ignore them.  Your game will work fine but everything will just render black where those textures should be used.

Comment: Oh..thanks. But I only use 3D models. I haven't got any textures. The size of the 3d models can be big. But is it affects the render? (I imported them from C4D as fbx and just used the scale tool to reduce the size.)

Comment: Just my "me too" comment... did you managed to solved it? Until today, I haven't seen this problem. But I have created a new scene as every other else, that works perfectly fine when I play it within the editor, but it is just black in Android. I know it is working, though, because the sound effects are playing as expected, but it shows nothing but a black screen there.

Comment: @Fran I was able to fix it. The problem was (for me) that I used  camera effects (from the standard assets) and my phone couldn't handle it. I read the documentation and I saw that most phones couldn't handle it

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment, not enough rep.

Anyway, there are lot of things that can cause a black screen to happen on Android. Here are a few to look at -

- Be sure your camera is not getting deactivated (in your case maybe not).
- Are you using any plugin that is using alpha channel or stencil buffer?
- Any other plugin that may causing this, disable them to check.
- Is your 24/32 bit buffer ticked/not on build settings?
- Double check your camera settings, lighting.
- Stripping level to disable and rendering path on build settings etc.
- Check the game on another device.
- Provide more info about the scene here

There's definitely something on that specific scene.

Comment: You can check it out: [link](http://gaborvecsei.itch.io/tinylittleplanet) . You can see that it work when you press start but when I tst in on my android device it's just a black screen with the texts. (maybe it's not rendering my 3D modells...or I don't know...)